# Python HTTP Error 416: Requested Range Not Satisfiable

Tags: python, urllib2

```
import urllib2

url = 'http://www....'
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders.append(('User-Agent' , 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)')) 
c = opener.open(url)
```

With this code, I get this error:

```
HTTP Error 416: Requested Range Not Satisfiable
```

How could I resolve ?

Comment: Either the data you're requesting is [out of range](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7233#section-4.4), or maybe the site you're trying to access doesn't like your User-Agent, so it's being uncooperative.

Comment: @PM2Ring I tried without user-agent and I get the same result.

Comment: @PM2Ring What can I do to avoid the "out of range" problem ?

Comment: Does the URL work properly in a browser?

Comment: The server shouldn't return a 416 code if you're not including a Range header in your request. What is the full URL? If it keeps happening on any URL you're trying, there might be another problem(a misconfigured proxy, etc.)

Comment: I can't reveal the url, but it doesn't happen on any URL, but only with a specific url.

Comment: It's not easy to debug problems with virtually no information. Can you at least reveal the query string of the URL?

Comment: @PM2Ring it's the homepage, so no query string

Comment: In that case, I'm inclined to think that my User-Agent theory is correct, since (as tuxmaul said) you shouldn't get a 416 code when there's no Range header in your request. If the URL works properly in a browser (and you're sure that things aren't getting mangled by a badly-configured proxy), try using an honest User-Agent string. Eg, see [the example User agent string](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page#Identifying_your_client) suggested by MediaWiki.